# Counties in Map Chart in Spotfire?

Tags: duplicates, geocoding, spotfire

I have a list of Counties that I would like to map in Spotfire. However, since some county names are duplicated in the US, spotfire is putting the information from certain counties in the wrong state (i.e. info associated to Adams County is going to Illinois instead of Mississippi). How does Spotfire deal with these duplicate entries? Is there a way for me to fix it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you add the state in your datatable as well then you can set both state and county as geocoding references. If I look in the county table for the USA, there are 12 Adams counties. All have different x and y coordinates.

If you just map on Adams the data might be put on 12 different Adams counties or on the first one Spotfire encounters.

You can look at the full geocoding information by going to the library and find the geocoding tables. In the folder countries / USA just open the USA Counties file. It will automatically create a map chart. But turn this into a table and you can see all the entries.

If you want to change some records, that is possible. Just export the data as a stdf file, open it with a text editor like notepad++ and adjust the records you want. Load the file and export it into the geotables. Check the help files how everything works exactly. And make a backup of the original files first.